# Redundant LDAP Servers

Tags: ldap

We have rhel 7.2 in our envirement.We have configured One LDAP servers in our envirement.That Server is working fine.

How to create High availability LDAP server so if one goes down other server can work as Ldap server.For that we have configured one more LDAP server with same configration.

Please suggest how can we proceed next.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a LDAP replica, and then use haproxy to balance thee requests - when primary LDAP is working, route all requests to it (replica is read-only), when it fails - everything goes to replica.

Comment: Thanks for the reply............Can you share some URL for the same??........